# Problema com dicionário - AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, dicionário, int

Estou começando a aprender o básico no Python, e um dos exemplos sobre listas de dicionário pede algo assim:

```
inventory = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : 6 , 'c' : 42 , 'd' : 1 , 'e' : 12}

def DisplayInventory(stuff):
    for k,v in stuff.items():
        stuff = k + v.get(stuff,0)
        print(k+v)

DisplayInventory(inventory)
```

Só que eu continuo tendo esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 8, in <module>
    DisplayInventory(a)
   line 5, in DisplayInventory
    stuff = k + v.get(stuff,0)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: em cada iteração, k vai ser uma chave (primeiro vai ser a, depois b, depois c etc.) e v vai ser o número correspondente a essa chave no dicionário (1, 6, 42 etc.). Não faz sentido fazer "get" num número. Nem eu e nem o Python estamos entendendo o que você quis fazer aí, por isso o erro. Explique qual saída você quer porque você provavelmente está no caminho errado. Faça o [tour] e dê uma lida em [ask] pra saber como fazer perguntas mais fáceis de serem respondidas.

Comment: A intenção do exercício que eu tentei fazer é exibir com o print algo como o nome da chave mais o nome do valor dessa chave

Comment: O que você quer fazer nesta linha "stuff = k + v.get(stuff,0)" ?

Answer (score 1):

O erro aconteceu pois você tentou chamar um método que não existe em `int`.

> `v.get(stuff,0)`

Como você explicou depois nos comentários que queria apenas mostrar a **chave** e **valor** de cada elemento em `inventory`, consegui chegar no seguinte código a partir do seu:

```
inventory = {'a' : 1 , 'b' : 6 , 'c' : 42 , 'd' : 1 , 'e' : 12}

def DisplayInventory(stuff):
    for k,v in stuff.items():
        print(str(k) + ' ' + str(v))

DisplayInventory(inventory)
```